# Unable to receive events from server in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack

i'm having problem using events in my servicestack application.
I'm creating an SOA applicatin based on ServiceStack. I've had no problem creating a simple GET/POST manager within the host. 
Now i would like to add events

I'm trying using an example, but the event is not received by the client

Does someone have an idea about that?

This is my server:

```
ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;

ServerEventsFeature serverEventsFeature = new ServerEventsFeature()
{
    LimitToAuthenticatedUsers = false,
    NotifyChannelOfSubscriptions = true,
    OnPublish = (res, msg) =>
    {
        //fired after ever message is published
        res.Write("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        res.Flush();
    },
    OnConnect = (eventSubscription, dictionary) =>
    {
    },
    OnSubscribe = (eventSubscription) =>
    {
    }
};
Plugins.Add(serverEventsFeature);

container.Register<IServerEvents>(c => new MemoryServerEvents());
container.Register(c => new FrontendMessages(c.Resolve<IServerEvents>()));
container.Register<IWebServiceEventManager>(c =>  new WebServiceEventManager(DeviceManager, macroManager));

SetConfig(new HostConfig
{
    DefaultContentType = MimeTypes.Json,
    EnableFeatures = Feature.All.Remove(Feature.Html),
});

public class FrontendMessage
{
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class FrontendMessages
{
    private readonly IServerEvents _serverEvents;
    private Timer _timer;

    public FrontendMessages(IServerEvents serverEvents)
    {
        if (serverEvents == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serverEvents));
        _serverEvents = serverEvents;            
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var ticks = 0;
        _timer = new Timer(_ => {
            Info($"Tick {ticks++}");
            _timer.Change(500, Timeout.Infinite);
        }, null, 500, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    public void Info(string message, params object[] parameters)
    {
        var frontendMessage = new FrontendMessage
        {
            Level = "success",
            Message = message
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Sending message: " + frontendMessage.Message);
        _serverEvents.NotifyChannel("messages",  frontendMessage);
    }
```

This is my client:

```
public async void Connect()
{
    try
    {
        Task.Delay(2000).Wait();
        clientEvents = new ServerEventsClient("http://127.0.0.1:20001/", "messages");
        clientEvents.OnConnect = (msg) =>
        {
        };

        clientEvents.OnHeartbeat = () =>
        {

        };
        clientEvents.OnCommand = (msg) =>
        {

        };
        clientEvents.OnException = (msg) =>
        {

        };
        clientEvents.OnMessage = (msg) =>
        {

        };
        Dictionary<string, ServerEventCallback> handlers = new Dictionary<string, ServerEventCallback>();
        handlers.Add("messages", (client, msg) =>
        {

        });
        clientEvents.RegisterHandlers(handlers);

        await clientEvents.Connect();
        client = (IServiceClient)(clientEvents.ServiceClient);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd first recommend [looking at ServerEvents Examples](http://docs.servicestack.net/server-events#serverevents-examples) and the [docs for the C# ServerEventsClient](http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-server-events-client) for examples of working configurations.

Your extra `ServerEventsFeature` configuration isn't useful as you're just specifying the defaults and the `Publish()` new-line hack is not needed when you [disable buffering in ASP.NET](http://docs.servicestack.net/server-events#response-buffering-delaying-events). So I would change it to:

```
Plugins.Add(new ServerEventsFeature());
```

Second issue is that you're use of [Message Event handlers](http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-server-events-client#message-event-handlers) is incorrect, your C# `ServerEventsClient` is already connected to the `messages` channel. Your handlers is used to listen for messages sent to the `cmd.*` selector (e.g. `cmd.FrontendMessage`).

Since you're publishing a DTO to a channel, i.e:

```
_serverEvents.NotifyChannel("messages",  frontendMessage);
```

You can use a [Global Receiver](http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-server-events-client#the-global-receiver) to handle it, e.g:

```
public class GlobalReceiver : ServerEventReceiver
{
    public void Any(FrontendMessage request)
    {
        ...
    }
}

client.RegisterReceiver<GlobalReceiver>();
```

Comment: Thanks. I give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mythz!
It works correectly.

Next step is to replicate the same behaviour on javascript client (events and get/post request). Do you have something to suggest me?

Thanks a lot!
Leo